# what to do if in python we get valueERRor

Tags: python

I have tried this statement

```
N,T,M = list(map(int,input().split()))
```

and python is showing me

```
N,T,M = list(map(int,input().split()))
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 1)
```

What to do?

Comment: You have to understand what `input().split()` does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you're receiving this error because you are trying to assign three distinct values (N, T, and M) even though your list only has one value:

By running this in the Python3 terminal, we see the same error you reported:

```
>>>N,T,M=list([1])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 1)
```

With 2 items in the list, the error message changes:

```
>>> N,T,M=list([1, 2])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)
```

If you have 3 items in your list, Python will assign one item to each of your variables:

```
>>>N,T,M=list([1, 2, 3])
# This works and no error is received
```

Then, with 4 items in the list, Python complains:

```
>>> N,T,M=list([1, 2, 3, 4])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3)
```

Essentially, you need to ensure that the number of items on the right side of your expression will be three in order to instantiate three separate variables.